# SQL not executing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-insert

The first SQL is executing but the second one doesn't seem to work.
When i change the query to the first one it works just fine but when I put it like that it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

I've just started learning MySQL i'm really struggling with this one and understanding the language.

```
 //Classic One that checks if the hwid is there
    public void checkHWID(string HWID)
    {
        string line;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            con.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE HWID = @HWID", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HWID", HWID);
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        line = reader[1].ToString();
                        Console.Write(line);
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        updateHWID(HWID);
                    }

                }
            }
        } 
    }

    //This one doesn't seem to update the hwid but when i change the query to the first one it works just fine
    public void updateHWID(String HWID)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO USERS(hwid) VALUES(@HWID)", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HWID", HWID);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's no call to `ExecuteNonQuery` in `updateHWID`. (Also, you probably don't want to call a function that *inserts* a row `updateHWID`, that's just asking for trouble.)

Comment: Use a Try Catch and see exactly why its not working. Are you trying to insert or update?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Any reasons why that is bad/not correct?

Comment: A method named `updateHWID` strongly suggests that it would execute an `UPDATE`, not an `INSERT`. It's conceivable that you have a system where "updating the HWID" on a higher level is implemented by inserting a row in the `USERS` table -- just not very likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL statement in the updateHWID function isn't working primarily because it is missing the code that executes the command you created.

```
connection.Open();
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO USERS(hwid) VALUES(@HWID)", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HWID", HWID);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();  // ADD THIS LINE
}
connection.Close();
```

Then assuming your table only requires the hwid and no other columns then this could work. If your table has other columns that don't allow nulls then you may get an error for the missing column values.